# Check if date is Valid java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method in java to check if a date is valid
Format MM/dd/yyyy

```
public static boolean checkDate(String date)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year=0,month=0,day=0;
    int year2;

    year=Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6));
    day=Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5));
    month=Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2));

    year2=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if(date.length() != 10)
        return false;
    if(year==year2||year<=year2-100)
        return true;
    else if(month>12||month<1)
        return true;
    else if(day<1)
        return true;
    else if(month==2&&day>28)
        return true;
    else if((month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12)&&day>31)
        return true;
    else if((month!=1||month!=3||month!=5||month!=7||month!=8||month!=10||month!=12)&&day>31)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

For some reason its not working and I have no idea why. If anyone can see if I made a simple mistake please let me know.

Comment: You could use something simpler - See this example  - https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-valid-date

Comment: There are quite a few reasons why your posted code might not work; you should **not** be using `Calendar` for one thing.

Comment: Your if-else (s) are wrong like "if (day < 1) then return true" why?

Comment: `if(year==year2||year<=year2-100)` ← What is the point of that?  Is the date automatically valid if it’s a 2020 date or occurs before 1921?

Comment: Yes. I repeat what Elliot Frisch says, so more of your screen is covered with their important comment: you should **not** be using `Calendar`: it's obsolete, outdated, archaic and antique. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974242/507738) answer for example.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
try 
{
    LocalDate ld = 
        LocalDate.parse( 
            "01/23/2021" , 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" )
        ) 
    ;
}
catch ( DateTimeFormatException e )
{
    … handle faulty input
}
```

## `java.time.LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatException`

Never use the terrible date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `Date`. Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse your input as a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Trap for the [`DateTimeFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) thrown if the input is faulty.

```
try 
{
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
}
catch ( DateTimeFormatException e )
{
    … handle faulty input
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

**edit(adding checks for year)**

Assuming you are using Java 8, The below code checks if  -

- The format is correct (MM/dd/yyyy)
- If the year entered is less than current year
- If the year entered is more than (current year - 100)
- If it has 31 days, 30 days, or leap year
- If there is any accidental strings in the input string except
  integers

Imports - `import java.text.*;` and `import java.time.*;`

Logic -

```
 private static boolean checkDate(String dateStr) {

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);

        try {
          sdf.parse(dateStr);

          int currentYear = Year.now().getValue();
          String str[] = dateStr.split("/");
          int year = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

          if(year > currentYear || year < currentYear-100){
            return false; 
          }

        } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException ex){

          return false;  // Returns false if parsing fails (in case of bad input).
        }

        return true; // Returns true for valid date Strings
     }
```

Test -

```
        System.out.println(checkDate("02/09/2021")); // Returns false
        System.out.println(checkDate("02/09/2020")); // Returns true
        System.out.println(checkDate("02/09/1900")); // Returns false
        System.out.println(checkDate("02/31/2020")); // Returns false
        System.out.println(checkDate("11/31/2020")); // Returns false
        System.out.println(checkDate("05/23/2020")); // Returns true
        System.out.println(checkDate("abc/23/2020")); // Returns false
        System.out.println(checkDate("05/23/efg")); // Returns false
        System.out.println(checkDate("02/29/2016")); // Leap year. Returns true
        System.out.println(checkDate("02/29/2019")); // Not a Leap year. Returns false
```

Comment: He want to check also if year is previous then the actual one

Comment: @lettomobile Updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

#### I run your code with "01/11/2019" it returns false.

A few things I have spot in your code in function of checkDate.
I am going to leave comments.

```java
public static boolean checkDate(String date) {
          //1. Target: String date = "MM/dd/yyyy" 
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          int year=0, month=0, day=0;

          int year2;

          year=Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6));
          day=Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5));
          month=Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2));

          year2=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          //2. this check will in the very beginning for the safety purpose, if the date string length is not 10, it will false, no need to do above work.
          if(date.length() != 10)
            return false;

          if(year==year2||year<=year2-100)
            return true;
         //3. Here is a obviously error, month is from 1 to 12, so change here to else if (month <= 12 && month >= 1)  
         else if(month>12||month<1)
            return true;

         //4. else if(day >= 1 && day <= 31) 
         else if(day<1)
            return true;

         //5. else if(month == 2 && day >= 28)
         else if(month==2&&day>28)
            return true;

         //6. else if((month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12)&&day==31)
         else if((month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12)&&day>31)
            return true; 

         //7. else if((month== 4||month==6||month==9||month==11)&& day ==30)       
         else if((month!=1||month!=3||month!=5||month!=7||month!=8||month!=10||month!=12)&&day>31)
            return true;
         else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your reasons but I suggest you using SimpleDateFormat class because you can choose the pattern and format the date as you want. Here is a really simple example similiar to what you posted so you can take a look

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()));

    String s = simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    String [] array = s.split("/");

    int year=Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
    int day=Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    int month=Integer.parseInt(array[0]);

    if(year > 2000 && year < 2020) {
        //To Do
    }
    if(day <= 31) {
        //To Do
    }
    if(month <= 12) {
        //To Do
    }
```

Output :

```
    01/01/1970
```

Comment: Why use the old libraries now that java.time is available? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html